# ChildViewController in UIContainerView has wrong height on initial load

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios-autolayout, uicontainerview

I have a ViewController that has content in the top third and then a UIContainerView in the bottom two thirds of the view. The UIContainerView allows the user to rotate between three childViewControllers. Using AutoLayout, I have constrained the UIContainerView to the sides of the screen (widthAnchor), the bottom of the screen (bottomAnchor) and two thirds of the way up the screen (topAnchor).

In laying out content in the first childViewController, which appears on the initial load of the parent ViewController, I ran into difficulty. It appears that on that initial load, the childViewController view is given a view.frame.height equal to the height of the device. I set up my constraints to deal with that and the first screen displays fine.

The issue I am running into now is that when I rotate through the childViewControllers, the view.frame.height is set to the height of the ContainerView (which I would have suspected to be the case from the start). This causes the constraints in the first childViewController to "break".

Look at this behavior below.

Image #1: Initial load of the ParentViewController.

https://roryent.box.com/s/xhil4wk0ga5qoddhko5jxj3a1r4103h3

Image #2: Switching the childViewController.

https://roryent.box.com/s/9f2jj0l1waui3ekyplq4eae51m6wrqn5

Image #3: Coming back to the initial childViewController. The constraints "work" but are reacting to a different view.frame.height.

https://roryent.box.com/s/cj9ffyy3m9oh8f523l2vsdezo1frk12x

NOTE: I am creating the constraints in the ChildViewController class and trying to use the frame of that childViewController frame to do so.

I have attempted to move the methods for constraining the items into willLayoutSubviews() in the childViewController with no change.

I suspect that there is something wrong with where I am loading the different items.

I would expect the self.view.frame.height used in the childViewController code reflect the height of the UIContainerView that is displaying it. In my case the height should be .67 * UIScreen.Main.Bounds.Height.

Comment: This does not sound at all right. To test, create a new `UIViewController`. Ctrl-drag from your `UIContainerView` to the new VC and select "Embed". Your new VC should immediately change to the size of the container view. Add 4 labels to the new VC, and constrain them to the 4 corners (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right). Run the app, and see if the 4 labels show up in the 4 corners of the container view as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue was due to my implementation of the ContainerView and its corresponding childViewControllers.

I have rebuilt the feature following this tutorial and have not had any problems. https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/